# What does "nosse" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

What does *nosse* mean? I cannot find it in Lewis & Short. For example:

*Quam ob rem, quod quaesivit ex me P. Apuleius, homo et multis officiis mihi et summa familiaritate coniunctus et vobis amicissimus, ita respondebo ut ea quibus non interfuistis **nosse** possitis.*

The grammar at the end of the sentence seems a little confusing.

Comment: You can find it [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=nosco&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059). I think it's a contracted form of *novisse*.

Comment: Note: Both [Collatinus](https://outils.biblissima.fr/en/collatinus-web/index.php) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nosse#Latin) will point you to the underlying verb *nosco* if you just enter *nosse*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a contraction of *novisse*.
Both *novisse* and *nosse* are listed in [the L&S entry for *nosco*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=nosco&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
It's a typical contraction in perfects with V, akin to *amavisse > amasse*.